# Getting content from other pages and use URL Parameters

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic, url-parameters

so here goes my first real coding question ever on the web since normally I try to find stuff out myself, but his time, I'm really stuck.

To see what i have so far: [see this webpage](http://hiremartie.com/wizapptest/wizard.php)

---

**What I want to achieve:**

The company that I work for at the moment wants me to create a "wizard", that solves a WiFi related problem, by selecting your situation, and expanding on that. In the end, it needs to be implemented into a Joomla powered website, so I figured the way to go was, load everything into one page.

---

**How I'm approaching it**

I first went to look for a way to load other pages into one main page. I achieved this by the use of JavaScript ([Found on this website](http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/load-remote-content-into-div-element.html))

After figuring that out, I started creating my "follow up" pages, and everything went well until I came to a page that would filter it's contents by grabbing the URL Parameter.

For the people interested in the tooltip function see [this page][3]

---

**What's the problem**

I use an If Else loop, to filter out the possible options, and if none of these are found, the page should give me the following "Het ziet er naar uit dat er iets fout is gegaan" or in English, "It appears something went wrong". Since this is the message I get, something in fact did go wrong. And after looking through my code, over and over, I figured it might be because of the URL parameter that it doesn't grab.

I thought of going for a static page link (Just link the button to a unique page), but I did some calculations, and for that to work, I would need around 70+ pages, which feels like a waste.

---

**The Code**

This is my code so far:

**My main page**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>EnGenius WiFi Wizard</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
    $(""+elementSelector+"").load(""+sourceUrl+"");
    }
    </script>
<div id="content">
  <h1>De WiFi Wizard</h1>
    <h3>Snel en gemakkelijk een draadloze oplossing</h3>

  <div id="btnholder" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', 'speed.php');"><div         id="button">Mijn internet is te langzaam</div></a>
            <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', 'router.php');"><img         src="images/tip.png" style="float:left; margin-left:3px;" alt="WiFi tip" width="15"         height="15" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Internet snelheid word ook wel aangeduid met het         woord Bandbreete', 250);"
    onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" />
            <div id="button" style="margin-left:10px;">Ik heb een router nodig,         Maar weet niet welke</div></a><img src="images/tip.png" style="float:left; margin-        left:3px;" alt="WiFi tip" width="15" height="15" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Een router is         een apparaat wat een netwerk met het internet verbind', 250);"
    onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" />
  </div> 
    <h3>Wat is Wifi eigenlijk?</h3><br />

    <h4>WiFi is een verzameling van standaarden voor draadloze netwerken.

    Wat houdt dit nou precies in?
    Heel makkelijk gezegd: Internetten zonder lastige lange kabels! 
    Je kunt bv met jouw laptop lekker op de bank zitten en genieten van internet.<br />        <br />

    Als je thuis een draadloos netwerk wilt dan heb je een product nodig waar dus de         standaard/naam ‘802.11’ op staat.<br />
    Helaas zijn we in Nederland een behoorlijk bepakt (woon)gebied. Hierdoor kun je         bijvoorbeeld storing hebben op jouw (technische) producten die je thuis gebruikt.<br /><br         />

    Ook met WiFi kunnen er situaties voorkomen waarbij je geen optimaal gebruik kunt         maken van de oplossingen die worden aangeboden.<br /><br />
    Via deze website kom je op de hoogte wat nou al die termen eigenlijk betekenen en
    welke oplossingen er zijn voor bepaalde situaties, kortom je wordt een echte WiFi         kenner!<br />
    <br />
    </h4>       
</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

---

**My second page content**

```
               <h1>De WiFi Wizard</h1>
            <h3>Dus u heeft een probleem met de snelheid van uw internet? Dat gaan we oplossen!</h3>
            <h3 style="font-size:10pt; color:#666666;">Wat is de afstand tussen uw computer en uw router?</h3>

            <div id="btnholder" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', 'detail.php?prob=010');"><div id="button">0-10 Meter</div></a>
            <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', 'detail.php?prob=1030');"><div id="button" style="margin-left:10px;">10-30 Meter</div></a>
            <a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', 'detail.php?prob=30');"><div id="button" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:90px;">Meer dan 30 Meter</div></a>
            </div> 
            <br />
            <h3>Waarom is afstand zo belangrijk?</h3>
            <br />

            <h4>Een WiFi signaal reist door de lucht, en kan worden verstoord door veel verschillende dingen zoals, muren, plafonds, andere apparaten, en andere WiFi signalen.</h4>
            <h4>Daarnaast verliest een signaal na verloop van tijd zelf ook sterkte, net als met geluid dat je over een grotere afstand steeds slechter hoort. </h4>
            <h4>Stel je voor dat je het signaal sterker kan maken, door een ander apparaat te gebruiken. Dat kan, omdat wij  altijd onderdelen van hoge kwaliteit gebruiken, kunnen wij ervoor zorgen dat uw WiFi signaal een beter bereik heeft, en u dus een snellere verbinding krijgt.<br />
            <br />
            </h4>
```

---

**My URL Parameter Page**

```
            <h1>De WiFi Wizard</h1>
            <?php   

            $prob = $_GET["prob"]; 

            if ($prob == 010)
            {
            echo "<h3 style='font-size:10pt; color:#666666;'>Nu we de aftand weten moeten we uitvinden hoeveel mensen er gebruik maken van het netwerk</h3>";
            } 

            if ($prob == 1030){ 

            echo "<h3 style='font-size:10pt; color:#666666;'>Nu we de aftand weten moeten we uitvinden hoeveel muren en/of plafonds er zich tussen de computer en de router bevindenk</h3>";
            }

            if ($prob == 30){ 

            echo "<h3 style='font-size:10pt; color:#666666;'>Nu we de aftand weten moeten we uitvinden hoeveel mensen er gebruik maken van het netwerk</h3>";
            }

            else{
            echo "<h3 style='font-size:10pt; color:#666666;'>Het ziet er naar uit dat er iets fout is gegaan</h3>";
            }                   



            ?>

            <div id="btnholder" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <?php   

            $prob = $_GET["prob"]; 

            if ($prob == 010)
            {
            echo "<a href='javascript:loadContent('#content', 'users.php?amnt=15');'><div id='button'>1-5 gebruikers</div></a>
            <a href='javascript:loadContent('#content', 'users.php?amnt=5');'><div id='button'>Meer dan 5 gebruikers</div></a>";
            } 

            if ($prob == 1030){ 

            echo "<a href='javascript:loadContent('#content', 'pen.php?amnt=none');'><div id='button'>Geen plafonds of muren</div></a>
            <a href='javascript:loadContent('#content', 'pen.php?amnt=1');'><div id='button'>1 Muur of Plafond</div></a>
            <a href='javascript:loadContent('#content', 'pen.php?amnt=2');'><div id='button'>2 Muren of Plafonds</div></a>
            <a href='javascript:loadContent('#content', 'pen.php?amnt=more');'><div id='button'>Meer dan 2 muren of plafonds</div></a>";
            }

            if ($prob == 30){ 

            echo "<a href='javascript:loadContent('#content', 'users.php?amnt=15');'><div id='button'>1-5 gebruikers</div></a>
            <a href='javascript:loadContent('#content', 'users.php?amnt=5');'><div id='button'>Meer dan 5 gebruikers</div></a>";
            }

            else{
            echo "-";
            }                   



            ?>

            </div> 
            <br />  
            <?php   

            $prob = $_GET["prob"]; 

            if ($prob == 010)
            {
            echo "<h3>Wat Maakt het aantal gebruikers uit?</h3>
            <br />

            <h4>Het aantal gebruikers bepaalt de hoeveelheid data die er word gebruikt binnen een netwerk. Hoe meer gebruikers er op een netwerk zitten, des te meer data word er gebruikt.<br />
            <br />Als het netwerk dit niet aankan, betekent het dat u een onstabiel, en traag netwerk krijgt, waardoor u niet optimaal van uw internet kunt genieten.</h4>";
            } 

            if ($prob == 1030){ 

            echo "<h3>Wat Maakt het aantal muren of plafonds uit?</h3>
            <br />

            <h4>Waneer een WiFi signaal door muren of plafonds heen reist, neemt het in sterkte af. Dus hoe meer obstakels er tussen uw router, en uw computer staan, des te zwakker het signaal.<br />
            <br />Door middel van de juiste onderdelen, denk bijvoorbeeld aan antenna's, kun je een sterker signaal creëren dat zich verder kan verspreiden.</h4>";
            }

            if ($prob == 30){ 

            echo "<h3>Wat Maakt het aantal gebruikers uit?</h3>
            <br />

            <h4>Het aantal gebruikers bepaalt de hoeveelheid data die er word gebruikt binnen een netwerk. Hoe meer gebruikers er op een netwerk zitten, des te meer data word er gebruikt.<br />
            <br />Als het netwerk dit niet aankan, betekent het dat u een onstabiel, en traag netwerk krijgt, waardoor u niet optimaal van uw internet kunt genieten.</h4>";
            }

            else{
            echo "-";
            }                   



            ?>
```

---

Sorry if my code is unclear, I need to get used to the whole pasting codes on websites, but at least I tried.

---

So for the **TL;DR** people among us. In Short:

I need to filter a php page with url parameters, but It can't seem to grab the parameter, because the URL doesn't directly change.

To see what I have so far: [see this webpage](http://hiremartie.com/wizapptest/wizard.php)

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug. Open the debugger - open the NET tab and you can watch the HTTP request/response and see what's going on.

Comment: What about using `location.hash` in Javascript?

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response! thats just great! The problem seemed to be a file that still needed to be updated on my remote server. But Thanks to all for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the parameter that is being appended to the AJAX request is different than the parameter that the PHP code is looking for.

From your wizard home page, if you click on "My Internet is too slow" (the first button translated by Google translate.) If you then click on any of the three buttons I get the error page you describe.  The url that is being requested is `/detail.php?id=010`, but your PHP snippet says that the script is looking for a `prob` GET parameter.

Try adjusting the parameter being sent to `prob` or the parameter that the PHP script is looking for to `id`.

Comment: Thanks, how stupid I didn't see that before. I didn't upload the file speed.php (which passes the variable) to the server yet. Together with the other answers given, I'm sure my script is solid now! Thanks for all your time :)

Answer (score 3):

You should put quotes around the values you're comparing against. For example, `010` would be interpreted as an octal.

```
if ($prob == '010') {
    ...
} else if ($prob == '1030') {
    ...
}
```

And so on.

edit: Also, as mentioned by Noah, no "prob" parameter is being passed in the URL, just "id". So you would assign `$prob = $_GET['id']`.

Comment: As commented on Noah's answer, thanks for the hints and the time. I also applied your method for passing the number through, and now i'm sure that the variable is always being processed as it should :)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the points already highlighted by [Noah Freitas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370576/noah-freitas) and [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383336/dan), I would recommend that you use a PHP [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) to travel through all possible values, its cleaner and the default option allows you to return an error value if nothing is found.

Also, check your variables with [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), don't assume their presence, otherwise:

- you take too long to debug your script;
- don't realize if anything is being passed;
- may get a php notice *(`Notice: Undefined variable`, or `Notice:
  Undefined index`)*;
- etc..

**PHP EXAMPLE BASED ON YOUR CODE**

```
<?php   

// check if variable is present to use it or pass empty
$prob = (isset($_GET["id"])) ? ($_GET["id"]) : (''); 

// switch by all possible values
switch ($prob) {

  case "010":
    echo "bla bla bla";
    break;

  case "1030":
    echo "bla bla bla";
    break;

  case "30":
    echo "bla bla bla";
    break;

  default:
    // This case matches anything that wasn't matched by the other cases
    // output error, or something...
    echo "-";
    break;

}

?>
```

Related to your script, you don't need to be using so many double quotes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
  $(elementSelector).load(sourceUrl);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I agree with you, that the php switch looks much neater, but since the script works as it does, and my php experience is a bit below level (I'm only an intern :p) so I'll stick to my current code for now. But I did learn from your post, and will be sure to use this method in the future! Thanks!